# change font color of content under ul , on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, haml

```
.text-right
    %ul#conversation
      %li
        %ul.btnClear
          %li
            - unless statement == Statement.featured.first
              = link_to "", display_featured_path(:current_featured_statement_id => statement.id, :direction => "previous"), :remote => true, :class=> "fa fa-play"
          %li
            - unless statement == Statement.featured.first
              = link_to "PREVIOUS", display_featured_path(:current_featured_statement_id => statement.id, :direction => "previous"), :remote => true, :class=> ""
```

---

trying to either put the ul under a button with a hover affect, or change all text under the ul on hover. I can get the individual a under the ul to change, but I need everything to change on the hover over -- when you hover over any portion of the ul. The font awesome icon and the link.

---

```
.btnClear:hover , li ul.btnClear:hover, ul#conversation li ul:hover{
color: #4dbbca !important;
/*background: transparent !important;*/
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
background-color: yellow;
```

}

---

I can get the background to change with the CSS above, but I need all text content under the entire ul. If I specify the > a , it just changes the individual 'a' on hover, not both at the same time, as you would expect.

Comment: sorry to sound like a noob , but what language/ framework are you using for the top code there?

Comment: @gerdi That's HAML, inside a Rails app (but it can be used without Rails).

Comment: Yes. haml. similar to jade And, bootstrap / rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess you have a space here:

```
.btnClear:hover , li ul.btnClear :hover, ul#conversation li ul:hover{
//------------------------------^^
```

That could be the issue.

It should be:

```
.btnClear:hover , li ul.btnClear:hover, ul#conversation li ul:hover{
```

without any space for psuedo selector.

---

*I need all text content under the entire ul.*

In this case you can try with this:

```
.btnClear:hover , li ul.btnClear:hover a, ul#conversation li ul:hover{
//------------------------------^^^^^^^^
```

A simple test case:

```css
.b:hover a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class='a'>
  <li>asdfasfd</li>
  <li>asdfasfd</li>
  <li>asdfasfdasd
    <ul class='b'>
      <li><a>asdfasfd</a></li>
      <li><a>asdfasfd</a></li>
      <li><a>asdfasfd</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No. that's not the issue. It was a typo, but thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: lol.. Thanks, man. Should have forgot about my pride and hit up Stack overflow a while ago..

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to target the hovered item and some of its children on hover? At the moment you've written three different selectors, but they're redundant because they're all targeting the same event on the same element (just with different specificity).

As I mentioned, I'm not totally sure what it is that you're trying to do, but here's a few tips on how you might be able to achieve it:

```
.btnClear:hover { ... } // targets .btnClear when it's hovered
.btnClear:hover ul { ... } // targets a ul inside .btnClear when .btnClear is hovered
.btnClear:hover a { ... } // targets an anchor inside .btnClear when .btnClear is hovered
```